# CSS - Alinhar imagem dentro de tabela com css inline

Tags: table, css

Preciso alinhar uma imagem ao texto da outra célula na tabela. O css está inline. Segue o código:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; padding-left: 30px;">
                <img src="[URL DO LOGO]" style="width: 50px;">
            </td>
                <br>
            <td style="padding-left: 5px; display: inline-block; width: 480px;">
                <div style="width: 480px; color: #757575; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-align:left;">Lorem ipsum.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: O `display: inline-block` nas TDs ferra com tudo. E você quer que fique alinhado como?

Comment: no meio da celula...

Comment: dá pra tirar o `display: inline-block`

Comment: Use `text-align: center; vertical-align: middle` no estilo da TD. E remova o `display: inline-block`.

Comment: não deu certo!!

Answer (score 2):

No seu código eu encontrei um padding-left `<td style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; padding-left: 30px;">` na coluna da imagem e, se você removê-lo, aparentemente dá certo.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display: inline-block; width: 50px;">
                <img src="~/Content/Imagem/Politica/avatar1.jpg" style="width: 50px;">
            </td>
            <br>
            <td style="padding-left: 5px; display: inline-block; width: 480px;">
                <div style="width: 480px; color: #757575; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-align:left;">Lorem ipsum.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remova o `padding-top:10px;` da segunda TD e tente isso;

```
    <html><head><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <table style="border: solid 1px black">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50px; padding-left: 30px;">
                        <img src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/facebook_416x416.jpg" style="width: 50px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 5px; width: 480px;">
                        <div style="width: 480px; color: #757575; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 10px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;">Lorem ipsum.</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Você pode ver o resultado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi com um `align="middle"` fora do css direto no html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 55px; padding-left: 30px;">
                <img src="[LOGO]" style="width: 55px;" align="middle">
            </td>
                <br>
            <td style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; width: 480px; text-align:left;">
                <div style="width: 465px; color: #757575; font-size: 12px;">Debitamos R$ [VALOR1] de sua conta no Paypal no dia [DATA] às [HORA]. Seu produto será enviado por [LOJA], e você receberá no seu endereço em até [PRAZO].</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```